# 6-pins ATX power for PCI slots 2, 3, 4, & 5

Tags: power, atx

I have EVGA’s Z77 FTW motherboard as described here: http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/visual/151-IB-E699_Visual_Guide.pdf

There are two inputs for 6-pins ATX power for PCI slots 2, 3, 4, and 5. One connector is just above slot 1 towards the left end and the other connector is at the lower left corner of the motherboard (90-degrees bent connector).

My PSU is Corsair AX850. http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=697193

One 8-pins connector (EPS) is available in the green boxed rectangle in the above illustration.

My question is “Can I use an 8-pins cable with a Y-splitter and detach 2 pins from the motherboard end and then plug in the 6 pins into the PCI ATX power connectors?”

Suggestions for alternate approaches are also welcome.

Comment: The first line isn't even a sentence or a question, and it's not clear what its trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 6pin-atx power connector that I know of, you must mean what is usually called PCIe-power. You have no PCI ports on that motherboard, those ports are called PCIe x16.

Yes you can use an Y-splitter and detach 2 pins. It would, however, be useless as the use for the connector is to give more power to the motherboard. If you use an Y-cable it will be the same thing as only connecting the power to the PCIe-card directly. I am talking about 8-pin PCIe-power not EPS.

It is possible to do what you want to though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The 6-pins connector on the motherboard just above PCI slot #1 is clearly marked "ATX_PWR_6-pin". Ditto with the 6-pins connector at the lower bottom corner. http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/visual/151-IB-E699_Visual_Guide.pdf This is why I am asking the question.

Comment: 6-pin atx does not look like that. 6-pin atx was used for extra power in the early p4-era and carries 5V 3.3V and GND. Your connector carries 12V and GND. The connectors also look very different. http://www.allpinouts.org/images/c/c8/Connector_mbpow_ataux_6pin.png thatswhat the 6 pin in the ATX standard looks like.

Comment: Gunnish, thank you for your reply!This is why I am concerned and thought that I could run it by the experts here on this forum. I even wondered whether the silk screening on the motherboard was wrong.